# Seating and tickets for children under 6 on all-reserved trains in Japan

Tags: tickets, japan, children, japan-rail

In Japan, the JR companies in their grandmotherly kindness permit children under 6 to travel for free on all trains...  [except](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/ticket/types.html):

> Fares and Charges for Infants and Babies
>
> Infants and babies travel for free, except that they need child's
>   tickets in the following cases.
>
> 1. When three or more infants accompany
>      one adult or a child (tickets are required for the third and any
>      additional infants).
> 2. *When an infant or baby occupies his or her own
>      reserved seat, Green Car seat or berth, etc.*
> 3. When an infant travels alone. *[Ed.: How does that work!?]*

So if I'm traveling with two infants on an all-reserved train, I need to buy a ticket if I want to *ensure* that they have seats.  Fine, that makes sense, but here's the question:

If I want to try my luck on an all-reserved train that's likely *not* full, **can children under 6 board without a reservation and sit in seats that happen to be free**?  Or am I required to hold them in my lap [all the way](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64082/stopovers-on-shinkansen-services), even if there are plenty of free seats around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, infants (children under 6) occupying a reserved seat need to pay the full child fare, period. *(It is not unusual in Japan for children to travel alone, although under 6 is probably rare.)*

In practice, if there are available seats, it is likely that nobody will care, including the train conductor (from personal experience).